# s.bind((host,port)) - nodename nor servname provided, or not known in Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.6

On a project that included a host(me)... this was written:

[image: screenshot]

and I got this :

[image: screenshot]

socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Here's what's supposed to happen:: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cuyu3VU0yD4&frags=pl%2Cwn

Does any of you have a solution???

Comment: Please don't add text as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the code snippet and the error message directly in your question.

Anyway: It is not recommended to use hostnames to bind a socket. What you actually bind sockets to are available network interfaces (which are represented by IP addresses). If you put some string into the `host` section in `s.bind((host, port))` which is not actually a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address, the string will be replaced with the first IP address the DNS returns for that string. If you want your program to behave predictibly on all computers, use IP addresses or just bind to all interfaces.

Possible solutions:

1. As long as you only need the connection to work locally on your computer, use `host = 'localhost'` or `host = '127.0.0.1'`
2. If you want it to work within your LAN, you could just bind the socket to *all* available network interfaces by using `host = ''` or `host = '0.0.0.0'`. If the computer you're running the program on is a regular PC it most likely only has one network adapter besides localhost anyway. As long as you don't forward the port you are binding the socket to to your external IP address, given to you by our ISP, devices from outside your LAN will not be able to connect to that socket.
3. If you want to properly iterate through your available network interfaces and their corresponding IP addresses, use a library like **netifaces** or **ifaddr**.

Here is an example with *ifaddr* (install with `pip install ifaddr`):

```
import ifaddr

def get_available_ip_addresses():
    addresses = []
    for adapter in ifaddr.get_adapters():
        for ip in adapter.ips:
            if ip.is_IPv4:
                addresses.append(ip.ip)
    return addresses
```

This method returns a list of all IPv4 addresses of network adapters available on the computer the program is running on (as strings which can directly be used with the socket library).

```
s = socket.socket()
lan_addresses = [addr for addr in get_available_ip_addresses() if addr[:3] in ['10.', '172', '192']]
host = lan_addresses[0]
port = 8080
s.bind((host, port))
```

This will bind the socket to the first IPv4 address returned by the function I defined which lies in the conventional LAN address space. On most regular home PCs, connected to a router which provides the LAN with an internet connection, `get_available_ip_addresses()` as defined here will return two addresses: `['127.0.0.1', '192.x.x.x']` where the second is some address your computers network adapter has been given by your router.

Hope I could help.

Cheers,
Silas

Comment: What about the slave program?It keeps saying :    s.connect((host,port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused. What did I do wrong ?? my firewall is not open

Comment: Are you running master and slave program on the same or on different computers? If on different ones, are they in the same LAN? What IP addresses did you use? We need to see your code and get some context information, otherwise we can not help you.